# Physical meaning of phase-plane representation

Tags: phase-space

If I have a dynamic equation I know I can represent it in the phase- plane ($x$,$\dot{x}$) and there I can study the stability of the system just looking at the shape of the curve: if it is an ellipse the system is stable, whereas if I have an hyperbola it is unstable.

But what is the physical meaning of this way of representing a dynamic system?

Are there other informations I can extract from it?

Answer (score 2):

What I find useful in phase plots, is that it allows you to see [limit cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_cycle). Those are cycles to which a dynamic system can converge and can be more complex than an elipsoid. These shapes are easier to see in the phase plane than in time traces.

You already mentioned some options for the trajectory. Also, if the trajectory crosses with itsself, the system is externally excited. If it spirals to one point it is dampened.

Comment: Do you know where I can find some more infos about the possibile trajectories? I did not know there could be other options and I would like to learn more about it

Comment: I had this in a lecture, but without adequate notes. I think this looks alright: http://www.math.utah.edu/~gustafso/f2008/dynamicalSystems.pdf